# не работает визуальный редактор категории woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Установила плагин yoast seo для хлебных крошек, после этого не работает редактирование категории товара woocommerce(доступна вкладка текст, а вкладка визуально не отображается), причем категория успешно добавляется.  Как исправить сию ситуацию.... Если я деактивирую плагин yoast seo, то вкладки все доступны, однако не знаю, какой лучше плагин бесплатный добавить для хлебных крошек...чтобы работало для страниц и woocommerce. спасибо.

Comment: Все наоборот. По умолчанию в WP нет визуального редактирования категории товара. Оно появляется при установке Yoast. Отключите все остальные плагины и проверьте.

Comment: Сегодня обнаружил... Та же ерунда на одном из сайтов.
При чем yoqst у меня не установлен. вукомерс и вп последней версии.